# Pass subarray by reference (not by value) in Common Lisp

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, common-lisp, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

Let's suppose I have an array - which I will call `*my-array*` - that looks like this:

```
#2A((1 2 3)
    (4 5 6)
    (7 8 9))
```

and I wish to apply some function f on the subarray

```
#2A((5 6)
    (8 9))
```

I'd love to be able to write

```
(f (subarray *my-array* '(1 2) '(1 2))
```

where `subarray` takes as arguments:

- the original array
- a 2-element list with starting point and ending point on the 1st dimension
- another 2-element list with starting point and ending point on the 2nd dimension
- etc.

I am looking for some way to pass the subarray as argument to function `f` *by reference* (or *by pointer*?) instead of *by value*.

(The dumb way to address this would be to write a function that creates (in this specific case) a 2*2 array and loops over i and j copying values from the original array. However, if you are dealing relatively large arrays, this would be quite costly.)

I found there exists a [`cl-slice`](https://github.com/tpapp/cl-slice) package but I do not get whether it copies values or accesses data by reference.

Comment: [are you sure that arrays are passed by value](http://ideone.com/ewsi78)?

Comment: @WillNess OP is not saying that arrays are passed by values. But if someone want to have a subset of a multi-dimensional array as another (possibly multi-dimensional) array, then the elements must be copied.

Comment: If I write a subarray function that creates an n*m 2D array (in the case of my example, n=m=2) and loops over i and j copying values from the original array, I feel almost certain that arrays will be passed by value.

Comment: @DannyZuko Everything is passed by value, but the value can either be a primitive (for integers, characters) or an implicit pointer to some memory (arrays, structures), in which case you'll share references to the same elements in the original array and its copy.

Comment: @coredump see? yes he does. -- the point I was trying to make was that AFAICS, what the OP really wants is the narrowed view into the same array, so that updating the narrowed array updates the original - hence the *"by reference"* reference. but it is enough to just pass the original array, and limit the allowed range of indices somehow.   which is exactly what the answer by sds looks like doing.

Comment: @WillNess There seem to be a confusion about by value and by reference in the question. When you ask OP whether he is sure that arrays are passed by value, this is confusing because it is so, like for any other object (and that does not imply necessarly a copy but only a local rebinding). I added some confusion myself, sorry, but I think we are on the same page. By the way, did you notice I have the same approach in my answer, which was posted before the edit from sds which introduces its macro?

Comment: @coredump but I wasn't asking, I was providing a link to an ideone entry which clearly shows that arrays are passed by reference. :) -- your answer makes a list of (shared) subarrays, right? I thought even that is superfluous. the addition of putting them in a vector is nice.

Comment: @WillNess This is the same thing as explained in [Java is Pass-By-Value, Damnit](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm). Arguments in CL are [passed by values](http://pastebin.com/Pyv0TzBz) because you don't change the bindings of the caller, only the ones of the callee. *But*, the value being passed might refer to an object, in which case we can mutate said object. This is the case here. This is not the same thing as pass-by-reference, which is what I'am trying to explain.

Comment: @coredump yes, right. perhaps it's helpful to say that in case of an array `arr` being passed as an argument `a`, calling `(setf a ...)` doesn't change `arr` but `(setf (aref a ...) ...)` does, to illustrate that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Lisp has [Displaced Arrays](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_d.htm#displaced_array) which are exactly what you are asking about (see [`array-displacement`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ar_dis.htm) &c).

However, in your case, displaces arrays are no help [because](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_aacba.htm):

> Multidimensional arrays store their components in row-major order; that is, internally a multidimensional array is stored as a one-dimensional array, with the multidimensional index sets ordered lexicographically, last index varying fastest.

This means that your subarray is *not* a contiguous section of your main array, and, thus, you cannot create another array displaced to it.

PS. If you cannot figure out how [cl-slice](https://github.com/tpapp/cl-slice) works, you can use `time` to see how much memory it uses and make your inference from that.

PPS. It is, in fact, not too hard to whip up something like what you want:

```
(defmacro slice (array &rest ranges)
  "Return an accessor into ARRAY randing in RANGES."
  (let ((args (loop for r in ranges collect (gensym "SLICE-ARG-")))
        (arr (gensym "SLICE-ARRAY-")))
    `(let ((,arr ,array))
       (lambda ,args
         (aref ,arr
               ,@(loop for arg in args and (lo hi) in ranges
                   for range = (- hi lo)
                   collect
                     `(progn
                        (unless (<= 0 ,arg ,range)
                          (error "~S is out of range [0;~S]" ,arg ,range))
                        (+ ,lo ,arg))))))))

(defparameter *my-array*
  #2A((1 2 3)
      (4 5 6)
      (7 8 9)))

(defparameter f (slice *my-array* (1 2) (1 2)))

(loop for i from 0 to 1 do
    (loop for j from 0 to 1 do
        (format t " ~S" (funcall f i j)))
    (terpri))
 5 6
 8 9
```

Comment: You could write `(lo hi) in ranges`; also, if there are less ranges given than dimensions, it is possible to let the anonymous lambda takes a `&rest others` arguments and use `(apply #'aref ,@(...) others)`. Nice macro by the way.

Comment: Yes, you could write that, but it would not mean what I want it to. Also, I like the fact that the macro does the implicit error checking.

Comment: I am puzzled. Do you have an example where the result differs whether using `first/second` or destructuring?

Comment: Looks like you are right (I tried destructuring in an early version of the macro and it did not work - for a different reason as I now realize). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As others pointed out, you cannot use displaced arrays for matrices (maybe you could with non-standard functions). But all you need is to change how you interact with the original array. Here are some possibilities.

#### Sequences of displaced arrays

```
(defun area (matrix tlx tly brx bry)
  ;; you may also want to check that all coordinates are valid
  ;; inside current matrix. You could generalize this function for
  ;; more dimensions.
  (assert (<= tlx tly))
  (assert (<= brx bry))
  (loop
     for y from tly upto bry
     collect (make-array (1+ (- brx tlx))
             :displaced-to matrix
             :displaced-index-offset
             (array-row-major-index matrix y tlx))))
```

(`tl` means top-left, `br` means bottom-right).

Then, assuming you define your matrix as follows:

```
(defparameter *matrix* #2A((1 2 3)
                           (4 5 6)
                           (7 8 9)))
```

... the sub-matrix is obtained as follows:

```
(area *matrix* 1 1 2 2)
=> (#(5 6) #(8 9))
```

... and accessed like this:

```
(aref (nth ROW *) COL)
```

Any changes to `*matrix*` is reflected in one of the two displaced arrays, and inversely.
**But** if you coerce the resulting list as a `vector`, then you'll have a vector of arrays. This is different from multi-dimensional arrays, but gives you constant time access for rows:

```
(aref (aref area ROW) COL)
```

#### Wrapper closure

Another way to provide a restricted view of the original matrix is to create an accessor function that works only for the ranges of interest:

```
(defun sub-matrix (matrix tlx tly brx bry)
  ;; again, you should do more checks
  (assert (<= tlx tly))
  (assert (<= brx bry))
  (lambda (x y &optional (value nil valuep))
    (incf x tlx)
    (incf y tly)
    (assert (<= tlx x brx))
    (assert (<= tly y bry))
    (if valuep
        (setf (aref matrix y x) value)
        (aref matrix y x))))
```

This returns a closure which takes 2 or 3 arguments. The first two arguments are `x` and `y` coordinates relative to the inner matrix. When given a third argument, the closure *sets* the value. Otherwise, it *gets* the value.

This can be made more generic. I was partly inspired by [sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077272/124319) but tried to do things a little differently; here I can generate either a setter or a getter function. I also add some checks before creating the function and during the execution of the created function:

```
(defun slice-accessor (array ranges mode)
  (let* ((dimensions (array-dimensions array))
         (max-length (length dimensions)))
    (check-type array array)
    (loop
       with r = (copy-list ranges)
       for range = (pop r)
       for (lo hi) = range
       for d in dimensions
       for x from 0
       for $index = (gensym x)
       collect $index into $indices
       when range
       do (assert (<= 0 lo hi d))
       and collect `(check-type ,$index (integer 0 ,(- hi lo))) into checks
       and collect `(incf ,$index ,lo) into increments
       finally (let ((body `(apply #'aref ,array ,@$indices ())))
                 (return
                   (compile nil
                    (ecase mode
                      (:read `(lambda ,$indices
                                ,@checks
                                ,@increments
                                ,body))

                      (:write (let (($v (make-symbol "VALUE")))
                                `(lambda (,$v ,@$indices)
                                   (check-type ,$v ,(array-element-type array))
                                   ,@checks
                                   ,@increments
                                   (setf ,body ,$v)))))))))))
```

#### CLOS

Once you have the above, you can provide a nice interface through objects. The setter and getter functions are updated whenever we change the ranges or the array being sliced:

```
(defclass array-slice ()
  ((array :initarg :array :accessor reference-array)
   (ranges :initarg :ranges :accessor slice-ranges :initform nil)
   (%fast-getter :accessor %fast-getter)
   (%fast-setter :accessor %fast-setter)))

(flet ((update-fast-calls (o)
         (setf (%fast-setter o)
               (slice-accessor (reference-array o) (slice-ranges o) :write)

               (%fast-getter o)
               (slice-accessor (reference-array o) (slice-ranges o) :read))))

  (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((o array-slice) &rest k)
             (declare (ignore k))
             (update-fast-calls o))

  (defmethod (setf reference-array) :after (new-array (o array-slice))
             (declare (ignore new-array))
             (update-fast-calls o))

  (defmethod (setf slice-ranges) :after (new-ranges (o array-slice))
             (declare (ignore new-ranges))
             (update-fast-calls o)))  

(defgeneric slice-aref (slice &rest indices)
  (:method ((o array-slice) &rest indices)
    (apply (%fast-getter o) indices)))

(defgeneric (setf slice-aref) (new-value slice &rest indices)
  (:method (new-value (o array-slice) &rest indices)
    (apply (%fast-setter o) new-value indices)))
```

#### Examples

```
(defparameter *slice*
  (make-instance 'array-slice :array *matrix*))

;; no range by default
(slice-aref *slice* 0 0)
=> 1

;; update ranges
(setf (slice-ranges *slice*) '((1 2) (1 2)))

(slice-aref *slice* 0 0)
=> 5

(incf (slice-aref *slice* 0 0) 10)
=> 15

*matrix*
=> #2A((1 2 3) (4 15 6) (7 8 9))

;; change array
(setf (reference-array *slice*) (make-array '(3 3) :initial-element -1))

(slice-aref *slice* 0 0)
=> -1
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to do exactly what you want to do. In memory, multidimensional arrays are implemented as a single flat array with some metadata which is used to convert from the multidimensional interface to the flat one. In your case `*my-array*` would look like this:

```
#(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

If you had the subarray you desired as a reference to the original array, it would look like this:

```
#(5 6 _ 8 9)
```

Which is impossible since you are trying to skip the `7` of the original array. If all of the desired elements were part of a contiguous sub-sequence, you would be able to use the `:displaced-to` argument of `make-array` in order to copy the sub-sequence by reference, but unfortunately, that is not the case.

Comment: Btw.: Kalman Reti shows how to do this on the Lisp Machine. See this video from 10:20 on. It allows displaced 2d raster arrays... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4-YnLpLgtk